# Класс с вложенным классом-массивом с методами управления этим массивом

Tags: delphi, массивы, классы, объекты

В ListView есть Items и SubItems. Код ниже добавляет к Item'у новый SubItem и получает ссылку на него для выставления свойств:

```
procedure P;
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView.Items.Add();
  Item.SubItems.Add('');
end;
```

Пытаюсь сделать наподобие, где будет возможность добавлять новые упражнения в массив упражнений через метод класса:

```
interface

{ Класс для хранения информации об упражнении }
type
TExerciseItem = class
private
  FName, FContent: String;
public
  property ExerciseName: String read FName write FName;
  property ExerciseContent: String read FContent write FContent;
end;

{ Массив упражнений }
type
TArrItemsOfExercises = array of TExerciseItem;

{ Класс для управления массивом упражнений }
type
TExercises = class
private
  FExercises: TArrItemsOfExercises;

  function GetExerciseItem(AIndex: Integer): TExerciseItem;
public
  property Items[AIndex: Integer]: TExerciseItem read GetExerciseItem;

  function Add(const ExerciseName, ExerciseContent: String): TExerciseItem;
end;

implementation

function TExercises.GetExerciseItem;
begin
  Result := FExercises[AIndex];
end;

function TExercises.Add;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := Length(FExercises);
  SetLength(FExercises, Count + 1);

  with FExercises[Count] do
  begin
    FName := ExerciseName;
    FContent := ExerciseContent;
  end;

  Result := FExercises[Count];
end;
```

Теперь описываю класс для хранения информации об уроке и какие упражнения к нему привязаны:

```
interface

{ Класс для хранения информации об уроке }
type
TLessonItem = class
private
  FName: String;
  FExercises: TExercises;

  function GetSubItem(AIndex: Integer): //Что должно быть здесь?;
public
  property LessonName: String read FName write FName;
  property SubItems[AIndex: Integer]: //И здесь? read GetSubItem;

  constructor Create();
end;

implementation

constructor TLessonItem.Create;
begin
  FExercises := TExercises.Create();
end;
```

И вот тут возникает вопрос: как использовать уже готовое решение из класса TExercises для управления массивом упражнений, чтобы можно было использовать методы этого класса.

После описания этого класса, я, по аналогии с классом упражнений, пишу дальше:

```
{ Массив уроков }
type
TArrItemsOfLessons = array of TLessonItem;

{ Класс для управления массивом уроков }
type
TLessons = class
private
  FLessons: TArrItemsOfLessons;

  function GetLessonItem[AIndex: Integer]: TLessonItem;
public
  property Items[AIndex: Integer]: TLessonItem read GetLessonItem;

  function Add(const LessonName: String): TLessonItem;
end;
```

Как мне доработать классы, чтобы можно было использовать вложенный массив упражнений, по аналогии с примером про ListView?

Answer (score 0):

```
TLessonItem = class
private
  FName: String;
  FExercises: TExercises;

  function GetSubItem(AIndex: Integer): TExerciseItem;
public
  property LessonName: String read FName write FName;
  property SubItems[AIndex: Integer]: TExerciseItem read GetSubItem;

  constructor Create();
end;

function TLessonItem.GetSubItem(AIndex: Integer): TExerciseItem;
begin
  result := FExercises.Items[AIndex];
end;
```

NB:

```
TExercises = class
...
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

destructor TExercises.Destroy;
var 
  iter: integer;
begin
  for iter := 0 to Length(FExercises) - 1 do
    FExercises[iter].Free;
  SetLength(FExercises, 0);
  inherited;
end;

function TExercises.Add;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := Length(FExercises);
  SetLength(FExercises, Count + 1);

  FExercises[Count] := TExerciseItem.Create; // !!!

  with FExercises[Count] do
  begin
    FName := ExerciseName;
    FContent := ExerciseContent;
  end;

  Result := FExercises[Count];
end;
```

Позвольте пару слов о выборе имен для элементов кода.

Я бы заменил `TExerciseItem` на `TExercise`. И уж точно бы убрал из названий свойств слово "Exercise". Речь и так идет о `TExerciseItem`, понятно, что свойства `Name` и `Content` относятся к "Exercise".

Comment: Не получается получить доступ к методу Add класса TExercises через экземпляр класса TLessons

Comment: Если в функции свойства GetSubItem возвращать не TExerciseItem, а TExercises, то я могу обратиться к методу Add этого класса, но в функции GetSubItem при указании Result := FExercises[AIndex]; выдает ошибку [Error]: Class does not have a default property. Может как-то нужно переписать классы, чтобы можно было обращаться к методам вложенного класса, как в примере-процедуре P в начале моего поста?

Comment: @Fasta `property Items[AIndex: Integer]: TExerciseItem read GetExerciseItem; default;`